# How do you mock Mongoose functions in Jest?

Tags: mongoose, jestjs

How do you mock mongoose calls like `find()`, `distinct()`, `count()`, `populate()`, etc.?

I tried out the Mockingoose npm package but it seems to be limited to just the basic calls like `find()` and although it says works with `distinct()` it requires that you return a document and will not allow you to return an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn()` and then `mockImplementation()` to mock the first call like `find()` and `update()`.  Here's an example of `findOneAndUpdate()` where we're checking to make sure the correct object is passed:

```
// TESTING:
// await Timeline.findOneAndUpdate(query, obj);
//

const Timeline = require("./models/user.timeline");
...
const TimelineFindOneAndUpdateMock = jest.spyOn(Timeline, "findOneAndUpdate");
const TimelineFindOneAndUpdate = jest.fn((query, obj) => {
    expect(obj.sendDateHasPassed).toBeFalsy();
    expect(moment(obj.sendDate).format()).toBe(moment("2018-11-05T23:00:00.000Z").format());
});
TimelineFindOneAndUpdateMock.mockImplementation(TimelineFindOneAndUpdate);
```

If you want to mock a chained function you can have it return an object with the next chained function you want to call.  Here's an example of how to mock a chained `distinct()` call.

```
// TESTING:
// let accountIDs = await Account.find(query).distinct("_id");
//
// WILL RETURN:
// ["124512341234","124512341234","124512341234"]
//

const Account = require("./models/user.account");
...
const AccountFindMock = jest.spyOn(Account, "find");
const AccountFindDistinctResult = ["124512341234","124512341234","124512341234"];
const AccountFindDistinctResult = jest.fn(() => AccountFindDistinctResult);
const AccountFindResult = {
    distinct: AccountFindDistinct
};
const AccountFind = jest.fn(() => AccountFindResult);
AccountFindMock.mockImplementation(AccountFind);
```

And after your test runs, if you want to check how many times a function is called like how many times `distinct()` was called you can add this:

```
expect(AccountFindDistinct).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
```